# Error in my restart level method

Tags: java, game-engine

this is the restart method:

```
 public void Restart() {
  object.clear();
  LoadImageLevel(loader.loadImage("/level.png"));
  cam.setX(-32);
 }
```

and this is the LoadImageLevel method:

```
   public void LoadImageLevel(BufferedImage image) {
  int w = image.getWidth();
  int h = image.getHeight();

  for (int xx = 0; xx < h; xx++) {
     for (int yy = 0; yy < w; yy++) {
        int pixel = image.getRGB(xx, yy);
        int red = (pixel >> 16) & 0xff;
        int green = (pixel >> 8) & 0xff;
        int blue = (pixel) & 0xff;

        if (red == 0 && green == 0 && blue == 100) {
           addObject(new Background(0, 0, ObjectId.Background)); // background
           addObject(new Block(xx * 32, yy * 32, 0, ObjectId.Block));

        }
        if (red == 100 && green == 60 && blue == 0) { // / block
           addObject(new Block(xx * 32, yy * 32, 0, ObjectId.Block));

        }
        if (red == 100 && green == 50 && blue == 0) { // /block 1
           addObject(new Block(xx * 32, yy * 32, 1, ObjectId.Block));
        }
        if (red == 100 && green == 40 && blue == 0) { // /block 2
           addObject(new Block(xx * 32, yy * 32, 2, ObjectId.Block));
        }
        if (red == 100 && green == 30 && blue == 0) { // /block 3
           addObject(new Block(xx * 32, yy * 32, 3, ObjectId.Block));
        }
        if (red == 255 && green == 255 && blue == 255) { // /block 4
           addObject(new Block(xx * 32, yy * 32, 4, ObjectId.Block));
        }
        if (red == 0 && green == 255 && blue == 33) { // /block up
           addObject(new Block(xx * 32, yy * 32, 5, ObjectId.Block));
        }
        if (red == 0 && green == 245 && blue == 33) { // /block up1
           addObject(new Block(xx * 32, yy * 32, 6, ObjectId.Block));
        }
        if (red == 128 && green == 128 && blue == 128) { // / box
           addObject(new Box(xx * 32, yy * 32, this, ObjectId.Box));

        }
        if (red == 150 && green == 150 && blue == 150) { // /
                                               // changedable
                                               // block
           addObject(new ChangeableBlock(xx * 32, yy * 32, this,
                 ObjectId.ChangeableBlock));

        }
        if (red == 255 && green == 0 && blue == 0) { // /red button
           addObject(new Button(xx * 32, yy * 32, 1, this,
                 ObjectId.Button));
        }
        if (red == 0 && green == 0 && blue == 245) { // /blue button
           addObject(new Button(xx * 32, yy * 32, 2, this,
                 ObjectId.Button));
        }
        if (red == 255 && green == 30 && blue == 30) { // ///ex
           addObject(new Ex(xx * 32, yy * 32, this, ObjectId.Ex));

        }
        if (red == 0 && green == 0 && blue == 255) { // / player
           addObject(new Player(xx * 32, yy * 32, this,
                 ObjectId.Player));

          }

        }
     }
   }
```

Now,the wierd thing is that 50% of the times it works and the other 50% it crashes with this error:

```
 Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.shuster.killtheex.objects.Box.tick(Box.java:37)
 at com.shuster.killtheex.window.Handler.tick(Handler.java:36)
 at com.shuster.killtheex.window.Game.tick(Game.java:84)
 at com.shuster.killtheex.window.Game.run(Game.java:66)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

And every time it happens with a different object..
Thanks alot!!

edit:
now I got this error..

```
   Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.shuster.killtheex.window.Handler.render(Handler.java:73)
        at com.shuster.killtheex.window.Game.render(Game.java:107)
        at com.shuster.killtheex.window.Game.run(Game.java:70)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: and line 37 of Box.java is?

Comment: Something is null in the line 37 of Box.java. (inside tick method)

Comment: if (tempObject.getId() == ObjectId.Block) {

Comment: but the problem is that it says that the error is in different object each time it crashes                                                         and now I got this error Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.shuster.killtheex.window.Handler.render(Handler.java:73)
 at com.shuster.killtheex.window.Game.render(Game.java:107)
 at com.shuster.killtheex.window.Game.run(Game.java:70)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)